# Currency format for Kendo Grid in Angular with Globalization

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, currency

I am using the kendo grid in Angular 4+. I need all the cells in a column to have a localized currency displayed.  Is this possible?

```
...
<kendo-grid-column 
  field="unitPrice"
  format="currency" // <- for clearity: I need to do something like this.
  [title]="Unit Price">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the kendo requires you to declare the format as well as provide the locale, like so.

**kendo column**

```
<kendo-grid-column 
  field="unitPrice"
  filter="numeric" 
  format="{0:c}"
  [title]="'formsPlus.lineItemAttach.unitPrice' | translate"
  [width]="100">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

**your.module.ts**

```
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from "@angular/core"
...

@NgModule({  
 ...   
 providers: [
   { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-US" },
 ],
```

For some reason It would not work without providing the `LOCALE_ID`.

**Side Note:**
You can change the language at startup by importing the locale into your module like so:

```
import "@progress/kendo-angular-intl/locales/fr/all"
...
  ...
  { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "fr" },
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, you can do it.
Check the below code from [Kendo UI Grid localization demo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/localization)

```
element.kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    pageable: {
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: true,
        buttonCount: 5
    },
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    columnMenu: true,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
        "ProductName",
        { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
        { field: "UnitsInStock", title:"Units In Stock", width: "140px" },
        { field: "Discontinued", width: "140px" },
        { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "", width: "260px" }],
    editable: "inline"
});
```

Observe that the field `UnitPrice` is formatted based on the `format` provided in the `column`
`{ field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" }`

For more reference, you can check [Kendo Localization documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/localization/overview)

---

**UPDATE:**

For Angular 2+, there won't be much difference.
You can have your markup as below.

```
<kendo-grid-column 
  field="unitPrice"
  format="{0:c}"      // or format="'{0:c}'" 
  [title]="Unit Price">
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: I think this is from AngularJS, I need Angular 2+

Comment: @ed-tester there won't be much difference for that. updated the answer